# Using variable as column name not working in MYSQL PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I apologize if my question does not make sense.  As you can see from the code below, it scans the PHP files, grabs the text between `{( )}` and stores it into `$match`.

Now what I am trying to do here is do a query on a table that looks for the column `$match` where the pageid is equal to the pageid from the URL and where the field(s) are not empty.  So far it is only returning Array in the text areas.

Am I setting up the code correctly or am I missing something simple?  I know the scanning portion is working because if I echo match I get the text between the `{( )}` areas.  It just isn't doing the query right for some reason. Or like I said I am missing something.  Any help would be great.  Please let me know if you need further information.  (I am not getting any MySQL errors).

```
$fn = "../templates/".$templateid.".php";

$file = file_get_contents($fn);

preg_match_all("#\{\('(\w+)'\)}#", $file, $matches);   

foreach ($matches[1] as $match) 
    {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE $match IS NOT NULL AND linklabel = '$pageID'") or die("Err: ".mysql_error());

    $res = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $content = $res;
    echo " <div id='tabs-".$match."'>
           <textarea id='".$match."' name='content-".$match."' class='fieldsetstyle'>".$content."</textarea>
                     <script type='text/javascript'>
                     CKEDITOR.replace( '".$match."' );
                     </script>
           </div>";
    }
```

Comment: Is column 'linklabel' of type pageID?

Comment: So, you're not getting any results? If you run the query directly on MySQL (via command line or phpMyAdmin or whatever) do you get results?

Comment: Can you show an example of what is put into `$match` - an example of what is found?

Comment: If I put the static column name into the query I do get the results I want, but this is a function that needs to be dynamic.

Comment: For Jonathan, example: {(test)} on templates page, test is stored into $match.  Query then searches table for test, and then should display the content in the column for the desired linklabel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$res IS an array, so try to output the correct column, like

```
echo $res['linklabel'];
```

or try var_dump()

```
var_dump($res);


$content = $res; // Still, $content is an array, not text
```

Comment: How would I be able to pull the content from the column that is equal to $match then..?

Comment: $res[$match] or $content[$match]

Comment: Thanks djot you did it!  Simply answer as always.

Comment: Thanks. Next time try at least to var_dump() everything from the beginning to the end/error to debug a script yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE ".$match." IS NOT NULL AND linklabel = '".$pageID."'") or die("Err: ".mysql_error());
```

Try This Update

Replace this

```
 foreach ($matches[1] as $match)
```

With this

```
foreach ($matches[1][1] as $match)
```

Comment: Tried this, still getting Array in the results.  No MYSQL error.

Comment: can u echo the query and show that query, so that i can review it ?

Comment: Yes, obviously I can't use a variable.  So when I put in the column name directly, it does return the desired results (the content in the field).

Comment: Broke the tabs jquery UI I had set up.  djot's answer worked.  Thanks though!